# spring batch causing spring data not to commit transaction

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have a spring mvc application with a batch process powered by spring batch . If i remove the batch configurations, all transactions commit. If a batch job is run, the batch job completes successfully but not data is commited to the database 
my configurations are as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = false)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableRabbit
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "zw.co.econet.workstation.repositories")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"zw.co.workstation"})
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return bean;
    }
}
```

Spring batch configuration :

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {
@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory steps;
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Qualifier("creditQueueItemWriter")
@Autowired

private ItemWriter queueItemWriter;
@Qualifier("creditQueueProcessor")
@Autowired
private CreditQueueProcessor creditQueueProcessor;
@Qualifier("creditQueueReader")
@Autowired
private CreditQueueReader creditQueueReader;
@Qualifier("transactionManager")
@Autowired
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;


@Bean
public AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
}

@Bean
@Autowired
protected Step creditSubscriberStep() throws Exception {
    return steps.get("creditSubscriberStep")
            .allowStartIfComplete(true)
            .startLimit(3)
            .chunk(10)
            .reader(creditQueueReader)
            .processor(creditQueueProcessor)
            .writer(queueItemWriter)
            .faultTolerant()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Job creditSubscribersJob() throws Exception {
    JobBuilder builder = jobs.get("creditSubscriberJob");
    return builder
            .start(creditSubscriberStep())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository());
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}


@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepository() {
    try {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("DEFAULT");
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}


@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer databasePopulator() {
    ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql"));
    populator.setContinueOnError(true);
    populator.setIgnoreFailedDrops(true);
    DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(populator);
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return initializer;
}
```

}

Credit writer :
    @Service
    public class CreditQueueItemWriter implements ItemWriter {

```
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
@Qualifier("creditQueueService")
@Autowired
private CreditQueueService creditQueueService;


@Override
public void write(List<? extends CreditQueue> list) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Processing credit list with size {}", list.size());
    for (CreditQueue creditQueue : list) {
        logger.info("Updating >>>> {} ", creditQueue);
        creditQueue.setProcessingState("PROCESSED");
        creditQueueService.save(creditQueue);

    }
    logger.info("chunk processed");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How do i get spring data jpa to persist as part of the batch run. With the configurations above, the batch runs to completion and updates the batch repository , but none of the JPA persist or merge functions commit the data to the database

Comment: Solved .  batch configuration to implement Batchconfigurer . @EnableBatchProcessing initiates its own transactionmanager hence the failure to persist the transactions